# Update table based on identical values in a column on same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
InsuredID   | EmployeeNumber    | MemberTypeID  | LinkedMemberID
----------------------------------------------------------------
1001012     | 39018             | 102           | 0
1001061     | 39018             | 100           | 0
1001147     | 39019             | 102           | 0
1001196     | 39019             | 100           | 0
```

I need to update `LinkedMemberID` in this table to value of `InsuredID` of the with same `EmployeeNumber` and `MemberTypeID = 100` for all MemberTypes which are not 100.

`LinkedMemberID` of `MemberTypeID = 100` will remain 0.

After update, the table should look like

```
InsuredID   | EmployeeNumber    | MemberTypeID  | LinkedMemberID
----------------------------------------------------------------
1001012     | 39018             | 102           | 1001061 
1001061     | 39018             | 100           | 0
1001147     | 39019             | 102           | 1001196 
1001196     | 39019             | 100           | 0
```

I have tried various SQLupdate statements but can't figure out how to do this. I am using SQL Server 2008. Please help.

Comment: Solved SQL Update Statement: Update t_policy_insured
    Set LinkedMemberID = t.InsuredID
    From t_policy_insured 
    Inner join t_policy_insured t on t_policy_insured.EmployeeNumber = t.EmployeeNumber and t.MemberTypeID = 100
    Where t_policy_insured.MemberTypeID <> 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want an `update` statement and you can do what you want with a `join`:

```
update toupdate
    set LinkedMemberID = t.InsuredID
    from table toupdate join
         table t
         on toupdate.EmployeeNumber = t.EmployeeNumber and
            t.MemberTypeID = 100
    where toupdate.MemberTypeID <> 100;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I was trying to write a similar update statement but couldn't complete it. Here is my full update statement:  Update t_policy_insured
    Set LinkedMemberID = t.InsuredID
    From t_policy_insured 
    Inner join t_policy_insured t on t_policy_insured.EmployeeNumber = t.EmployeeNumber and t.MemberTypeID = 100
    Where t_policy_insured.MemberTypeID <> 100

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `APPLY` function:

```
SELECT
    t.InsuredID,
    EmployeeNumber,
    MemberTypeID,
    LinkedMemberID = CASE WHEN t.MemberTypeID = 100 THEN LinkedMemberID ELSE x.InsuredID END
FROM tbl t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT InsuredID
    FROM tbl
    WHERE EmployeeNumber = t.EmployeeNumber
    AND MemberTypeID = 100
)x
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c6a8/1/0)

---

Transforming it to an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.LinkedMemberID = x.InsuredID
FROM tbl t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 InsuredID
    FROM tbl
    WHERE EmployeeNumber = t.EmployeeNumber
    AND MemberTypeID = 100
    ORDER BY InsuredID DESC
)x
WHERE t.MemberTypeID <> 100
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c6a8/2/0)

Comment: Your query: SELECT not UPDATE

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly. I did try the your code but I haven't used outer apply before. I am reading about it now and we hopefully be useful in another place.

Comment: No problem. I suggest you read these two excellent articles by Paul White on `APPLY`. [Part 1](http://http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/) and [Part 2](http://http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET LinkedMemberID = (SELECT TOP 1 T.InsuredID
                      FROM Your_Table T
                      WHERE T.EmployeeNumber = Your_Table.EmployeeNumber
                         AND T.MemberTypeID  = 100)
WHERE MemberTypeID <> 100
```

Comment: This worked too. The statement simple and easy to understand. thank you.